# Azure Cosmos DB: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

While connecting from my code outside of the company network, the Cosmos DB connection works just fine. But from the company network, it throws a `503 ServiceUnavailable` status code. What are the possible issues?

Comment: Please share the complete error details / exception. There is a public guide for them https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-service-unavailable

Comment: You can also try to connect to Cosmos DB using `Gateway` mode which uses port 443 (HTTPS) to connect. Otherwise, please see the link mentioned by @MatiasQuaranta.

Comment: System.Exception: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: ServiceUnavailable (503); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ; Reason: (The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 4 endpoints across 1 regions. Please check for client resource starvation issues and verify connectivity between client and server.

Comment: @Gaurav, Also, I don't see dedicated gateway option in my cosmos database instance. But i can see one in my development environment. Strange!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the comments:

```
System.Exception: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: ServiceUnavailable (503); Substatus: 0;
ActivityId: ; 
Reason: (The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 4 endpoints across 1 regions. Please check for client resource starvation issues and verify connectivity between client and server.
```

Normally, if you take that exception and store or view the `ToString()`, it will show you more information. But from the message itself, it means the client tried to connect to all known endpoints available and failed.

This normally means there is either something on the network blocking your request or the machine executing this code is completely overloaded (CPU at 100% or port exhaustion) and cannot process any request.

If this is consistently failing for all operations, check that your network has the correct port range open:

[image: Port ranges for each connection mode]

By default, the SDK works in Direct mode, so check that ports in the 10000 through 20000 range are open and available. If you have private endpoint enabled, the range is 0 to 65535.

As @GauravMantri mentioned, you can change to Gateway mode also if the network is restricted:

```
string connectionString = "<your-account-connection-string>";
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connectionString,
new CosmosClientOptions
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway 
});
```

Comment: Same issue here. Switched to using ConnectionMode Gateway fixed it. I pass in the options as mentioned here above and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem. Switching from Direct to Gateway connection mode instantly fixed the issue. For those who are curious about the implications of this, it basically routes traffic over HTTP/443 instead of using direct connectivity via a blocked port.